# oid Convert a double* to double

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

In my code I have to use a function that accepts a `double*` as an argument

```
void function_1(int a, double* var){
  (*var) = 0.;
  for (int i=0; i<a.Size(); i++) {
    (*var)+=pow(a[i],2);
  }
  (*var) = (*var)/a.Size();
}
```

Then I have to use `(*var)` in another function that needs var as a double

```
double function_2(double x)
```

I tried to use

```
function_2( *(double*) var )
```

but without any success... Since I am new to `c++` I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Any help on that?

Comment: What's the error actually? Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: function_2(*var) should do the trick. When you have *var on the left side of an expression, it means "follow the pointer and store this value in the section of memory it points to". When you use it on the right hand side, it means "follow this pointer and return the bytes stored in the section of memory it points to"

Comment: @JakeChristensen Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately `function_2` is a function from a library I have to stick with this...

Comment: `function_2( *(double*) var )` *should* have worked. The `(double*)` cast is unnecessary, since `var` is already of type `double*`, but it's harmless. You say it didn't work. *How* did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function 2 should accept a double all the same

```
function_2( double var );
```

and then you can call it with `*` like so:

```
function_2(*var);
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)'s a great and comprehensive tutorial on pointers and references (they are very related concepts in c++). It has some images that really make you understand this topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since I am novice in `c++` could you also give some more info and/or some reference? Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the answer and added a link to a great pointer/reference tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call it just use: `function_2(*var);`